# Login form is shown for a couple of second in iOS

Tags: codenameone

I have a login form & once the user logged in, this form should not be shown until user log out. I have used getFirstFormName method to do this and it works fine in android. But in iOS although the user has already logged in, the login form is shown for a couple of second.

```
@Override
    protected String getFirstFormName() {
        loginToken = Preferences.get("loginToken", null);
        if (loginToken != null) {
            return "MenuForm";
        } else {
            return "Login";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is a static image of the 1st screen of your app, you need to add a splash screen to your app to be the first screen.